# Set feature class based on IF statement in Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

My model  selects a feature class within a user specified file geodatabase,  based on the output of an IF statement which checks the user specified string value e.g. If the user specifies a file gdb `InputGDB` and a string `A`, the if statement checks the string and returns true if the string is A. it then chooses the appropriate feature class `FC_A` within `InputGDB` and continues processing.  The same thing happens if the user enters B, i.e. feature class `FC_B` would be chosen.

The same processes happen on the feature class, regardless of whether A or B is chosen. My problem is there is a third feature class, also sourced from the same gdb (let's call it `FC_Common`), whose processes always run regardless of what is happening with A/B. After some initial processing, `FC_common` must interact with A/B via a series of Intersect, Joins, selections etc. How do I set the model up so that I don’t have to duplicate the entire branch of processes for each option?

I've read a bit about the Merge Branch tool, and I think it's what I want, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it. I've attached an image of the model to show where I am having a problem.

[image: Model]